# POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQUneY3 400 (Bad Request) in ejs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ejs

I am very new to this socket.io.

I have the code this is a node server code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var socketIO = require("socket.io")(http);
var socketID = "";

socketIO.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("User is conneected ", socket.id);
  socketID = socket.id;
});
```

And here is the code for a ejs file:

```
......

<script src="/public/js/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
......
var socketIO = io("http://localhost:3000");
......
</script>
......
```

And the socket.io.js file is [here](https://github.com/Satyam-code143/CheckInRepo/blob/main/socket.io.js):

I tried but nothing is working. The same error pops whenever I refresh the page.
I am very new to this and I really want to get it sorted as soon as possible!!

I already have a listen function just after `socket.on`:

```
http.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server has started running!!");
  .........................
.............
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code is working for me.

```
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();
var server          = require('http').Server(app);
var io              = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log(socket);
})

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" > </script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var socket = io.connect();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I assume that the `socket.io.js` that you have mentioned is the same as that from the `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js` and still it's not working.

Comment: Then I think you should start websocket protocol insted of polling.
` var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000", {transports: ['websocket']});`

Comment: I think @NarendraKumawat is right `{transports: ['websocket']}` you should try it is working. with [latest 3.0.4](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js) link.

Comment: Now I am getting this error  ` GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) `. But the previous one has gone!

Comment: I think that it worked and this error is something else. Thanks a lot, @NarendraKumawat

Comment: Specifying the `{transports: ['websocket']}` did worked for me, I'm using the `socket.io-client` npm package

Answer (score 1):

socket.io.js that you have mentioned is the same as that from the https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js... check the installed version of serail io in package.json and place the same version here in the path socket.io/2.2.0 it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30015200)

Answer (score 0):

Please Check versions of socket.io in your Frontend and Backend. It should be compatible. I had same issue so I solved it with version change. Like I had 2.2.0 in my frontend so I install 1.7.2 in backend or same as frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my up to date (Jan 2024) solution with Typescript:

server.ts

```js
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import path from 'path';

const app: Express = express();
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {/* options */});

app.get("/", (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("./client/index.html"));
});

io.on("connection", function(socket: Socket) {
  console.log("a user connected");
  socket.on("message", function(message: any) {
  console.log(message);
  });
});

const server = httpServer.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("listening on *:3000");
});
```

./client/index.html

```html
<!-- ./client/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="sendMsg()">Emit Msg</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
      function sendMsg() {
        socket.emit("message", "HELLO WORLD");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

as was mentioned before it is important that the socket.io version on the server side matches the script src on the served page **4.7.3**:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.3/socket.io.js">
```